# Fluent Nhibernate, adding collation as part of convention

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, collation

Is it possible to control the collation generated by Nhibernate for all the columns of type nvarchar? Depending on the culture where the software is installed, it might be nice to control it from the installer which would read this option from configuration file.

I've found just ways of adding collation to concrete query results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can use a CustomSqlType to specify the collation for the column (using a NOCASE collation as an example):

```
public class CaseInsensitiveStringConvention : IPropertyConventionAcceptance, IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        // More work could be done here to ensure you get nvarchars only
        criteria.Expect(c => c.Property.PropertyType == typeof(string));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomSqlType("text COLLATE NOCASE");
    }
}
```